# Savon using built in request builder instead of raw xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

If i use savon with raw xml everything works fine, this is the raw xml example:

```
request = client.call(:authenticate, xml:'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="xxxx/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:authenticate>
      <ns1:username>user</ns1:username>
      <ns1:password>pwd</ns1:password>
      <ns1:cultureInfo>it</ns1:cultureInfo>
    </ns1:authenticate>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>')
```

If I use the builtin method to call the method I got an error, this is the code:

```
credentials={ username: 'user', password: 'pwd!!', cultureInfo: "it" }
response     = client.call(:authenticate, message: credentials)
```

This is the xml produced by the above code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:wsdl="http://tempuri.org/"
                xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Body>
    <wsdl:authenticate>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>pwd</password>
      <cultureInfo>it</cultureInfo>
    </wsdl:authenticate>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do just this (untested). It's not pretty but it works.

```
credentials = { 'ns1:username' => 'user',
                'ns1:password' => 'pwd!!',
                'ns1:cultureInfo' => "it" }
response = client.call(:authenticate, message: credentials)
```

You might want to adapt the use of `ns1` to the actually used namespace in your case.

Comment: Yes the namespace was the problem. I had to add also this in the savon client configuration: env_namespace: :soapenv,
                      namespace_identifier: :ns1)